# jAVASCRIPT: как заменить во всех ссылках, сами ссылки (без параметров) на другую ссылку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например:

```
<a href="/images/small/1.png?action=load">1</a>
<a href="/images/small/33sf.png?action=load&top=1">2</a>
<a href="/images/large/2.png?action=get&top=3">3</a>
```

все эти ссылки, до гет параметров нужно заменить на ссылку: `/redirect/temp/`.

результат:

```
<a href="/redirect/temp/?action=load">1</a>
<a href="/redirect/temp/?action=load&top=1">2</a>
<a href="/redirect/temp/?action=get&top=3">3</a>
```

как такое сделать на js/jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').each(function() {  
  let hrefExploded = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
  let result = `/redirect/temp/?${hrefExploded[1]}`;
  $(this).attr('href', result);
  
  console.log(result);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/images/small/1.png?action=load">1</a>
<a href="/images/small/33sf.png?action=load&top=1">2</a>
<a href="/images/large/2.png?action=get&top=3">3</a>
```